# Laravel MySQL SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry not solved

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, auto-increment

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry laravel, I have tried all solution on iternet. I am getting this error when adding new record, strang things is I am not getting this all time but error coming on every 2nd or 3rd record.

This I start noticing after import data from Backup

- I have truncate table and create from migration, but after importing old records still same issue.
- Have tried resetting auto increment field.

in controller I have tried 2 ways given below

'''

```
$data = array(
        'hospital_id' => $hospitalid,
        'doctor_name' => 'newdoc',
        'doctor_id' => $this->myGUID(), 
        'created_at' => NOW(),
        'updated_at' => NOW(),
        'status' => 0,
        'slug' => $docslug       
      );
      $doctor_id = Doctor::create($data)->id;

       $doct = new Doctor();
        $doct->hospital_id = $hospitalid;
        $doct->doctor_name = 'newdoc';
        $doct->doctor_id = $this->myGUID();
        $doct->slug =  $docslug;
        $doct->created_at = NOW();
        $doct->updated_at = NOW();
        $doct->status = 0;
        
        $doct->save();
```

'''

Comment: Is my question clear enough or need more details? I have put few days but still no solution

Answer (score 0):

check your migration, may some of your cols are unique and you are entering Duplicated value,

Comment: I have checked that, ID is the only unique column is in the table, and ID is set as the primary key with autoincrement. it's throwing an error for the ID field only.